# Highcharts: Negative values of the secondary axis should come below the x axis

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 axis(primary and secondary) in y axis using the attribute

```
opposite= true
```

But I want the negative values of the secondary axis to be below the x axis.Any guidance would be helpful.
http://jsfiddle.net/tpscz0q3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset` option for the xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
    offset: -140,
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h9tjmdxu/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted, like both y axis should start from 0 in the same line(positive 
 values of both y axis above the center line and negative values below the center line I hope you understand what I am trying to say). but is it possible the x axis and labels to be at the bottom.

Comment: Hi Raphael, Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1nwLzgqd/ ?